# Wordpress Get Image external link ('Link To')

Tags: wordpress, image, attachment, link-to

I have images in my post and I can display them with either:

```
  //$full_img_url = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
  //echo '<img src="'.$full_img_url.'">';
```

or

```
echo(wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID,'full'));
```

My images have all a link to an external URL (if you edit the image, it's the Link To metadata). However, I'm unable to find a way to get that external link ...

I've tried a var_dump of the attachments from my post, couldn't find it ...

Any idea where those links are stored?

Thank you

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/9z2jja/using-wordpress-attached-image-custom-url-outside-the-content

Comment: do you mean attachment page i.e `yourwebsite/some-post/some-image/` or img src of an image i.e `yourwebsite/wp-content/uploads/date/some-image.jpg`

Comment: When you put an image on a post, and edit the image, there is an option called Link To. What I want, in my template, it to display all the images, and when you click on the image, it goes to the URL defined in the Link To field. But somehow I can't retrieve it. And it's not in the get_post_meta(ID)

Comment: I see, where do you want to display this function. in single post or attachment page?

Comment: I want to display it in a post. My post contains images, with links. I'm using Masonry to display the images in the rendered page (post), and I would like to be redirected to the link when you click on an image.

Answer (score 0):

An attachment in WordPress is just another post, so the meta data should be stored in the `wp_postmeta` table. You can access it by using `get_post_meta($attachment->ID, 'KEY')`.

Comment: No, unfortunately the 'Link To' does not appear:

Comment: Are you using the correct key? You could retrieve all the metadata attached to the attachment with `get_metadata()`. See if that outputs anything with 'Link To' in it. You might specifically output the `_wp_attachment_metadata` key. 

Is there a specific plugin you're using that adds this field option?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code bellow it will display all image size ( thumbnail, medium , large) and link that image to image source

```
$sizes =  get_intermediate_image_sizes();
$attachment_id = 309; // test purpose 

foreach ( $sizes as $size ) {
    $imglink = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id , $size )[0]; //
    echo '<a href="'.$imglink.'"><img src="'.$imglink.'"></a>';
}
```

Hope this is what you looking for.

Comment: You code create a link to the image itself. I want the click to redirect to an external link. For example, if I have a Google image, I edit it and put www.google.com in the Link To field (in display settings), I want the click to go to google.com and not display the image source.